# How do i print the key inside a dictionary, with out the value?

Tags: python

For example

```
d= {1: [1,4,0], 3: [3,6,0], 2:[2,5,8]}
print d
```

I want the out put to give me

```
1 3 2
```

I have tried this `d[0]`
but it prints the value

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
There are plenty of on-line tutorials and documentation to show you how to access dictionary facilities.  How did *none* of these satisfy what you're missing?

Answer (score 3):

Just print the keys using [`d.keys()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_keys.htm):

```
>>> d= {1: [1,4,0], 3: [3,6,0], 2:[2,5,8]}
>>> d.keys()
[1, 2, 3]
>>> d.keys()[0]
1
>>>
```

---

Interestingly enough, `d[0]` should not actually return a value, it should raise a `KeyError` because it looks for the value that matches the key of `0`:

```
>>> d= {1: [1,4,0], 3: [3,6,0], 2:[2,5,8]}
>>> d[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
>>>
```

Comment: You might want to mention the fact that dicts are unordered. You cannot be sure the result will always be `[1, 2, 3]`, in that order.

Comment: If the dictionary is exactly as entered above it will always be `[1, 2, 3]` because the hashes are not random. However, if the values change then yes the keys may change.

Comment: It will always be `[1, 2, 3]` on your system, with your specific version of Python. It might be different for the OP. And it isn't `[1, 3, 2]`, as expected by the OP. OP might want to use another data type if the order is important.

Comment: @EricDuminil https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping states that it is hashing, which is not different per system.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. My point is just that dicts are unordered, and that you should mention it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through the key value pairs.  However, if you wanted all the keys printed on one line you would need to modify this a little.

```
 d= {1: [1,4,0], 3: [3,6,0], 2:[2,5,8]}

 for k, v in d.items():
     print(k)

 output:
 1
 3
 2
```